# Dynamicly defined function call inside module

Tags: javascript

There is a code, problem inside 'interpret': how to call any given function from 'func' inside, not just 'sum3'?

```
const sum = (...args) => {
    return args.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr)}

const defn = (functionName, args, body) => {
    let [func, ...params] = body;
    let result = `var ${functionName} = function(${args.join(',')}) { return ${func.name}(${params.join(',')})}`
    return result;
}

const interpret = (...code) => {
    let [dfStr, callString] = code;
    let [func, ...args] = callString;
    eval(dfStr[0](dfStr[1], dfStr[2], dfStr[3] ));
    return sum3.apply(this, args);
    }


const result = interpret(
    [defn, "sum3", ['a', 'b', 'c'], [sum, 'a', 'b', 'c']],
    ['sum3', 10, 20, 30]
)
```

Comment: Why do you `eval` the definition but not the call?

Comment: This code will do interesting things if you pass in e.g. `'}'` as one of the arguments...

Comment: did i? there is call sum3.apply(this, args); isnt it?

Comment: Or, better advice: if you're trying to build your own little Scheme, don't use `eval` at all but write the complete interpreter yourself, including scope handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you eval the function definition but not the corresponding call,

Check this out:

```js
const sum = (...args) => {
  return args.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr)
}

const defn = (functionName, args, body) => {
  let [func, ...params] = body;
  let result = `var ${functionName} = function(${args.join(',')}) { return ${func.name}(${params.join(',')})}`
  return result;
}

const interpret = (...code) => {
  let [dfStr, callString] = code;
  let [func, ...args] = callString;
  eval(dfStr[0](dfStr[1], dfStr[2], dfStr[3]));
  return eval(`${func}.apply(this, args)`);
}


const result = interpret(
  [defn, "sum3", ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    [sum, 'a', 'b', 'c']
  ], ['sum3', 10, 20, 30]
)
console.log(result)
```

TBH I have no idea what you are trying to do but keep in mind that using eval is an evil practice. Maybe you can think of a cleaner solution to fit the purpose.

**Update**:

```js
const sum = (...args) => {
  return args.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr)
}

const defn = (functionName, args, body) => {
  let [func, ...params] = body;
  let result = `(${args.join(',')}) =>${func.name}(${params.join(',')})`
  return result;
}

const interpret = (...code) => {
  let [dfStr, callString] = code;
  let [func, ...args] = callString;
  return eval(dfStr.shift()(...dfStr)).apply(this, args)
}

const result = interpret(
  [defn, "sum3", ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    [sum, 'a', 'b', 'c']
  ], ['sum3', 10, 20, 30]
)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: oh, you right, any idea why it doesnt work without second eval?

Comment: You've hardcoded `sum3.apply(this, args)`, you can get it work inside one eval or just think of a better solution as I mentioned.

Comment: @SamKazantsev Because without the `eval`, the function name `sum3` was hardcoded in `interpret`.

Comment: @jns yeah, i know about eval, i wonder where was `sum3` after first eval, `this` was empty